# getWidth ImageView and set height= 1.6*width

Tags: android

I have a segment Android code:

```
final int[] finalWidth = new int[1];
final ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
ViewTreeObserver vto = iv.getViewTreeObserver();

vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                iv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                finalWidth[0] = iv.getMeasuredWidth();    
                textView.setText(Integer.toString(finalWidth[0]));
                return true;
            }
        });
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.getLayoutParam().height = 1.6*finalWidth[0];
```

but , ImageView is invisiable after the app was built. Help me ! thanks you!

Comment: first of all..... `final int[] finalWidth = new int[1];` why is this an array ? why not `final int finalWidth;`? because i see u arent even using array

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `gifImageView` is your imageView.

```
gifImageView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int __w = gifImageView.getWidth();
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(__w, (int)(1.6 * __w)); // Since you can not apply float height
            gifImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
            gifImageView.invalidate();
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.